# How to add dependency to my pom.xml?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I want to use https://code.google.com/p/droidpersistence/source/checkout but I don't know how add to my pom.xml..

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided specifies a place you can download some code, using Subversion:

```
svn checkout http://droidpersistence.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ droidpersistence-read-only
```

So run that command, and it will download the code. That particular code is designed to be built with ant, instead of maven. You need to write a little pom.xml file for it, so that when you build it on your computer with "mvn clean install", maven will generate a .jar file (the artifact), and put it in your local maven repository (.m2 directory). Then add a dependency on that jar to your pom file.

In general, to add a dependency to your pom using the latest version of IntelliJ Idea (12.1.6), click somewhere in your pom file, and press ALT-INSERT, then choose "dependency".

Hope this helps!